# Files on OS SD card

Tags: sd-card

I have an SD card with NOOBS on it.

I need to transfer some files to it to run them on the PI.

May I write files to the sd card with the os on it without hurting the os? Is the OS loaded into memory on the PI?

Comment: How do want to write files on the SD card (read with which OS, in the Pi or using another system)? This is important insofar as Windows for example lets you only access the first partition on the card. Unless you do not overwrite files you're however fine to put additional files on the card.

Comment: Also, depending on the OS you use with your RPi you may be able to transfer files *via* the OS and utilities running on it.  E.g. if your planning to copy files from a PC running a *nix or MacOs and you are running Raspbian or another *nix on the RPi it is likely that you can use "`scp` filename on the PC `pi@raspberry://home/pi/`" to copy that file to (you can also retrieve a file with a known name from the remote system) the `pi` user's home directory on the RPi.  It is also possible to set up various file-system servers e.g. `samba` (CIFS sharing like Windows) or the *nix `nfs` system.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can write files directly to the card if you plug the SD card into another computer. It will not cause any harm to the OS, as long as you put the files in the right partition.